# ASP.Net Web API - How to unregister custom action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, filter

I have developed a custom action filter-**LogActionWebApiFilter** for Web API 2:

```
namespace Utility.Logger.WebApi.RequestResponse.Attributes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Log action web API action filter
    /// </summary>
    internal class LogActionWebApiFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        #region Private Fields

        /// <summary>
        /// The current identifier
        /// </summary>
        private static Guid currentId;

        /// <summary>
        /// The request start time
        /// </summary>
        private static DateTime requestStartTime;

        /// <summary>
        /// The logger
        /// </summary>
        private IEventLogger logger;

        #endregion Private Fields

        #region Public Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LogActionWebApiFilter"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logger">The logger.</param>
        public LogActionWebApiFilter(IEventLogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        #endregion Public Constructors

        #region Public overrided Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs after the action method is invoked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionExecutedContext">The action executed context.</param>
        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<NoLogWebApiFilter>().Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            // Some business logic

            this.logger.DebugFormat("API Call of {0}()", actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs before the action method is invoked.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext">The action context.</param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<NoLogWebApiFilter>().Any())
            {
                return;
            }

            // Some business logic
        }

        #endregion Public overrided Methods
    }
}
```

Now, I want to register/unregister this custom action filter run-time later after application started, based on a flag.

Here is my filter registration code:

```
public void StartLogging()
{
    var existingFilter
       = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.FirstOrDefault(
                   f =>
                       f.Instance.GetType().ToString().Equals(typeof(LogActionWebApiFilter).ToString()
                       ));

    if (existingFilter == null)
    {
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new LogActionWebApiFilter(this.logger));
    }
}
```

Here is my filter unregistration code:

```
public void StopLogging()
{
    var existingFilter
        = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.FirstOrDefault(
                    f =>
                        f.Instance.GetType().ToString().Equals(typeof(LogActionWebApiFilter).ToString()
                        ));

    if (existingFilter != null)
    {
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Remove(existingFilter.Instance);
        existingFilter = null;
    }
}
```

**Problem :-**

- On each `Application_BeginRequest()`-event, I check the flag (has some business logic), and based on value of the flag I call respective method out of above 2 methods.
- However, any of the above method doesn't work.
- Even filter is added into `System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters`, but `OnActionExecuting()` / `OnActionExecuted()` any of them are not invoked.

Please guide me, what's I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance,
Balaguru.

Comment: Instead of unregistering it, can you not control it's usage with a variable? At what point would it stop logging, same request?

Comment: Yes @BenSnaize, on same request if the flag is calculated as FALSE (based on some business logic), then logging should be stop.

Comment: Then the simplest solution is to add a value to `Request.Properties`in `StopLogging()` and `StartLogging()` to make the logical change e.g. `"ShouldLog", false`. You can then interrogate this in the Logging code under `actionExecutedContext`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to control the action filter in  Application_BeginRequest() event. Action filters are global Filters which can only register at Application_Start().

I would suggest , you can add or remove filter through configuration file.

```
<configSections>
<section name="filters" type="ConfigurableFilters.FiltersSettings,  AssemblyName "/> 
</configSections>

<filters>
  <add type="ConfigurableFilters.BarFilter, AssemblyName" />
  <add type="ConfigurableFilters.FooFilter, AssemblyName" />
</filters>
```

In that case you'll need a ConfigurationElement.

```
 Public class FilterAction : ConfigurationElement
{
[ConfigurationProperty("type", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
public string Type 
{
    get { return base["type"] as string; }
    set { base["type"] = value; }
}
}
```

And a ConfigurationElementCollection.

```
    public class FilterActionCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {       
       protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
       {  return new FilterAction();}

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
       {  return ((FilterAction) element).Type;}
   }
```

And a ConfigurationSection.

```
    public class FiltersSettings : ConfigurationSection
    {
      public static FiltersSettings Settings
       {
          get {
             var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("filters")
                      as FiltersSettings;
             return section ?? new FiltersSettings();                
              }
        }

     [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
     public FilterActionCollection Filters
       {
        get { return base[_filtersProperty] as FilterActionCollection; }
        set { base[_filtersProperty] = value; }
       }

    private readonly ConfigurationProperty _filtersProperty = 
    new ConfigurationProperty(
        null, typeof (FilterActionCollection), null, 
        ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsDefaultCollection);
  }
```

One way to apply the configured filters is to use the following code during application startup:

```
    var filters = FiltersSettings.Settings.Filters;
    foreach (var filter in filters.Cast<FilterAction>())
     {
        var filterType = Type.GetType(filter.Type);
       GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(filterType));
     }
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhiraj for such a nice answer.
In contrast to your statement that "Filters can only register at Application_Start()", my same code is working fine for my MVC project. Only Web API is not behaving as per expectations. Strange!!!

Comment: I don't believe this code allows the application to manage logging dynamically as asked in the question. It is either on or off based on the config file and would require an edit to change this. The question seems to specify it should be a toggle during the request.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer here would be to add a toggle value to `Request.Properties` and interrogate this in your logging code.

```
public void StartLogging()
{
    // Check the value does not already exist etc. and either add or modify.
    if (actionContext.Request.Properties.ContainsKey("ShouldLog")) {
        actionContext.Request.Properties["ShouldLog"] = true;
    }
    else {
        actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("ShouldLog", true);
    }
}
```

In your Logger:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (actionContext.Request.Properties.ContainsKey("ShouldLog"))
    {
       // Parse and check the value of ShouldLog before returning when false.
       return;
    }

    // Some business logic
}
```